# Do not show expiration date information on Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am using the code below to report the time it takes for a post expires in my Wordpress site, the value of expiration I define in a Custom Field (expiration).

From this code, as I do I keep a post that will expire in about four hours, does not display the information in this way: "Expires in 0 days , 4 hours and 49 minutes."

I do not want the "0 days" is displayed, only the remaining hours. In the case of the post expires the next day, so good, could be displayed normally "Expires in 1 day, 4 hours and 49 minutes."

In addition, there are posts that I do not define expiration, and they all appear the following information: "Expires in 0 days , 2 hours and 0 minutes." How do I display information like "Undetermined Expiration" for these posts?

```
           <?php 
                $date_now    = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
                $date_expire = get_field('expiration');

                $now     = new DateTime($date_now);
                $expires = new DateTime($date_expire);

                $diff = $expires->diff($now)->format("%a days, %h hours and %i minutes");

                if ($now < $expires) {
                    echo "Expires em $diff", PHP_EOL;
                } 
                else if ($now >= $expires) {
                    echo "Expired!", PHP_EOL;
                }
                else {
                    echo "", PHP_EOL;
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$now     = new DateTime( $date_now );
$expires = new DateTime( $date_expire );

$diff = $expires->diff($now);

if( $diff->days ) $diff = $diff->format( "%a days, %h hours and %i minutes" );
else              $diff = $diff->format( "%h hours and %i minutes" );
```

`->days` is the only absolute `DateTime` property.

If you want display only minutes when the difference is lower than 1 hour, you can change above code in this way:

```
if( $diff->days  ) $diff = $diff->format( "%a days, %h hours and %i minutes" );
elseif( $diff->h ) $diff = $diff->format( "%h hours and %i minutes" );
else               $diff = $diff->format( "%i minutes" );
```

Comment: So perfect! Thank you fusion3k. What about the posts that I did not add expiration date and appear as follows: "expires in 2 hours and 0 minutes" How can I avoid this and add as "undetermined expiration".

Comment: Yes, but as I created a custom field with the ACF, this field appears in all posts, even those I do not add expiration. Perhaps the result is zero, but it shows the value "expires in 2 hours and 0 minutes".

Comment: when to retrieve the field, what is the content of `$date_expire`? Not the displayed `$diff`, the content of retrieved field: evaluate the `$date_expire` content for this.

Comment: I managed with $date_expire, thank you. One last question: how am using a lot of data comparison, somehow you can compromenter the server? My site may slow down?

Comment: It's depend to what means 'a lot', but I don't think that your site will slow down